# How to convert date to UTC in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert the today UTC date and add 24 hrs to it. Because I want to retrieve the data as per `startDateTime` and `endDateTime`.

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Today; //Today at 00:00:00
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //Today at 23:59:59
```

like above code does.

Comment: So `DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1)`?

Comment: You should read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

Comment: You want local time 00:00 to UTC?

Comment: Unrelated: Is the least significant timespan 1 second? If smaller, you'll have a gap of the one second between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it using `UtcNow.Date`

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date; //Utc Today at 00:00:00
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //Utc Today at 23:59:59
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/AILY97783

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date; //UTC Date
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); //UTC Date added 1 day
```

Comment: Doesnt do the same thing `Today` returns midnight (ie, start of the day)

Comment: the startDateTime returns utc date and time i want utc date and time is 00:00:00

Comment: i want to pass this `startDateTime ` and `endDateTime` to get the data as per date

Comment: Yes @Jamiec. You are correct. I made the edit to my answer now its a copy of yours :)